# TYPO3: Remove default wrapper

Tags: templates, typo3, wrapper

I have TYPO3 (7.6.10).
i have also tx_news.
I use fluid.

I want to remove the default wrapper for content elements.

I have:

```
<div><p>Text content</p></div>
<div id="c343"><article>New 1</article> <article>New 2</article> ... </div>
```

I want:

```
<p>Text content</p>
<article>New 1</article> <article>New 2</article> ...
```

How can i do that?
I tried in tsconfig:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
```

Comment: This idea is not very good. <div id="c343"> are uses as anchor. You can set a link from content to a element on another page and need thsi anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `<div id="c343">` It works only whith this solution:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject {
  key.field = CType
  default = TEXT
  default.value = 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove `<div id="c343">`, your solution is correct.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
```

Also possible

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.10.cObject.default.value
```

You can use the TypoScript Object Browser in module "Template" and search for `<div id="c{field:uid}"`

Did you clear frontend cache?

Answer (score 0):

Remove TYPO3 defult `<div id="c343">` wrapper `class` and `id`.

Use below **typoscript**

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default >
```